# Need help with a JavaScript function to determine ascending numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table rows, which have a *start* number and an *end* number (input fields).

Per row, the end **must** be larger than the start.

From inputs left to right, top to bottom the numbers must be larger than the last.

So there are 2 inputs per row, and 4 (for example) rows. Each number is bigger than the last.

I've been trying to validate this using this function

```
   var maxDepth = 0,
  didValidate = true;

// I assume this reads from left to right top to bottom as they are that way in the markup
$('.input-start-depth, .input-end-depth').each(function(i) {

  maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, parseFloat($(this).val(), 10));

  var isStart = ($(this).hasClass('input-start-depth'));
  var value = $(this).val();


  if (isStart && value > maxDepth) {
    didValidate = false;

    return false;
  };

  lastValue = value;

});
```

I've been racking my head to get this to work. The other important thing is the number of rows is dynamic, there could be 1 or 10,000 or any in between.

Basically it is meant to say if the start depth is larger than the max depth so far, it should fail.

But it is validating numbers when they shouldn't be valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: Fixing the indentation might clarify things a little... is that `if(isStart)` supposed to be there on line 11?

Comment: @sje397 Sorry, good catch. I removed some `console.log()`'s in there for the sake of clarity.

Comment: So if you have a 2x2 table (0, 1), (2, 3) (where , denotes a new row), is that valid?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can assume the order in which the elements are read. you should look into reading the table row by row. here's some code to look at to see what i mean:

```
$('table#mytable tr').each(function() {
  var start = parseInt($(this).find('.input-start-length').val());
  var end   = parseInt($(this).find('.input-end-length').val());
  if(start > maxDepth) {
    didValidate = false;
    return false;
  }
  lastvalue = start;
});
```

Comment: I `after()`'d the each iterator and it did go in the order I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using, which seems to work

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(i) {


                var startDepth = parseFloat($(this).find('.input-start-depth').val(), 10);
                var endDepth = parseFloat($(this).find('.input-end-depth').val(), 10);


                var anyNans = isNaN(startDepth) || isNaN(endDepth);

                if (anyNans || startDepth > endDepth || startDepth < maxDepth) {
                    didValidate = false;
                    return false;
                };
                maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, endDepth);

            });
```

Comment: Note that parseFloat only takes one parameter, unlike parseInt, where you probably do want to pass 10 as the second parameter.

Comment: Also note that you require endDepth >= startDepth and startDepth >= maxDepth which means that maxDepth is always the previous endDepth.